# “To book” or “to booking”?

Tags: adverbs, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, redundancy

I had a debate with my friend (English is not our mother tongue) because I found this phrase bit wierd.

> We were almost close to booking tickets to London.

1. I thought using 'almost' and 'close' together is not right.
2. We were both confused on this part: *to booking* tickets.
   Should we use *to book* or *to booking*?

Answer (score 2):

> We were almost close to booking tickets to London.

It's perfectly fine.

Consider: *I **look forward to** seeing you*

Here "to" is not a marker of the infinitive verb, it is a preposition, so the verb that follows is in the gerund (-ing).

And to be "almost close to" means you were *nearly doing* or *[about to](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about-to) do* something. The "almost" could be dropped entirely or substituted with ***very***, which is used to emphasize a description.

> We were very close to booking tickets to London.

*[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/close)* provides a definition and pertinent examples

> 1.3 (**close to**) Very near to (being or doing something)
>
> - ‘I had a low point towards the end of last season and that is why I was **close to leaving** the club, but now I am at my best ever level.’
> - ‘The attempt nearly succeeded as he was **close to being** able to get his head through the hole.’

---

references: ["To hear" or "to hearing"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing/18773#18773) and [Why was “to + verb+ing” used in this case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57230/why-was-to-verb-ing-used-in-this-case)

Answer (score 1):

"Almost close" is probably redundant.  I'd use simply "close."  Also, it's "weird."  I like to joke, "Put "i" before "e" except after "c," unless the word is foreign or weird.

Comment: It's certainly redundant, and I can't see any redeeming feature in this particular example. / '... or _weir_ or _seize_ or ...'

Comment: We could regard "almost" in "almost close" as an intensifier it stresses how far in the process of booking ticket to London they were.